# Is it necessary to have Ontology file and RDF data to be in the same database for reasoning or inference?

Tags: rdf, ontology, rdfs

I wanted to understand if it is necessary to store the Ontology or OWL file (as triples) in the database to perform any reasoning, the problem we are facing is incased if the Ontology needs to be updated then how would we update it?

The idea we thought about is to have the Ontology exposed somewhere on the web and use its reference while we do SPARQL query on the Database with triples, but what I would like to know if it is the right way of doing it? (It basically saves us updating the ontology inside a database)

Also if it is possible to expose it on the web then how should it be done? we are looking at storing and exposing it via s3 Bucket in AWS.

We have tried doing it by saving it in the database but would like to know if it is possible to decouple both in any way?

Answer (score 1):

That depends on how the underlying system performs reasoning. For systems that materialize, ie pre-compute, the inferences, you probably need to have the ontology & all of the data loaded into the database to be able to do the inferencing.

If you're using a system that performs reasoning at run time, then the data & ontology can be separate. You will get better query performance if the query engine can *access* the data during planning as there might be parts of the plan that are included because of the ontology, but in reality could be pruned given what's actually in the database.

Comment: Yes my usecase needs stuffs at real time for example we have a vehicle on the road and I need to calculate oil heat temp and alert the driver incase of any abnormal values, so in such kind of usecase do u suggest that I have it in different places? Also what are the best practices to expose ontology on web and refer during runtime

Comment: the ontology should be part of the database, putting it "on the web" isn't really a thing, you want it _with_ your data. But in a real-time use case like this, materialization might not be appropriate. You could certainly model things in such a way that it'd work fine, but, doing the reasoning at query time seems more appropriate.